# Create dummy variable column from value column

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I know that Pandas has a `get_dummy` function which you can use to convert categorical variables to dummy variables in a DataFrame. What I'm trying to do is slightly different.

I have a column containing percentage values from 0.0 to 100.0. I need to convert this to a column that has 1's for any value >= 10.0 and 0's for any value < 10.0. Is there a good way to do this repurposing `get_dummy` here or will I have to construct a loop to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can can convert bools to ints directly:

```
(df.column_of_interest >= 10).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're discussing [`pandas.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) here, and I don't think that this is a use case for it. You are attempting to set two values on a boolean condition. One approach would be to get a boolean Series and take the integer representations for indicators, with

```
df['indicators'] = (df.percentages >= 10.).astype('int')
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df

    percentages
0     70.176341
1     70.638246
2     55.078803
3     42.586290
4     73.340089
5     53.308670
6      3.059331
7     49.494812
8     10.379713
9      7.676286
10    55.023261
11     4.417545
12    51.744169
13    49.513638
14    39.189640
15    90.521703
16    29.696734
17    11.546118
18     5.737921
19    83.258049


>>> df['indicators'] = (df.percentages >= 10.).astype('int')

>>> df
    percentages  indicators
0     70.176341           1
1     70.638246           1
2     55.078803           1
3     42.586290           1
4     73.340089           1
5     53.308670           1
6      3.059331           0
7     49.494812           1
8     10.379713           1
9      7.676286           0
10    55.023261           1
11     4.417545           0
12    51.744169           1
13    49.513638           1
14    39.189640           1
15    90.521703           1
16    29.696734           1
17    11.546118           1
18     5.737921           0
19    83.258049           1
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a dataframe `df`, with a column `Perc` that contains your percentages:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.np.random.seed(111)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Perc": pd.np.random.uniform(1, 100, 20)})
```

Now, you can easily form a new column by using a lambda function that recodes your percentages, like so:

```
df["Category"] = df.Perc.apply(lambda x: 0 if x < 10.0 else 1)
```